# Flask: passing around background worker job (rq, redis)

Tags: python, session, redis, backgroundworker, flask

I want to do a very simple thing: Launch a worker to something and then return the answer to user.
I'm trying to do so using a combination of Flask and RQ.

```
import os
from flask import Flask, session
from somewhere import do_something
from rq import Queue
from worker import conn

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.secret_key = '....'

q = Queue(connection=conn)

@app.route('/make/')
def make():
    job = q.enqueue(do_something, 'argument')
    session['job'] = job
    return 'Done'

@app.route('/get/')
def get():
    try:
        session['job'].refresh()
        out = str(session['job'].result)
    except:
        out = 'No result yet'
    return out
```

The idea in this very simple example is that people go to /make/ and the job starts. After some time there can go to /get/ and the result from the worker will be printed there.

However one line is causing problems:

```
session['job'] = job
```

It seems the job cannot be pickled, which is apparently used by the Flaks session. I'm getting the error:

```
...
10:52:16 web.1     |   File "/Users/julius/twitter-sentiment/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 804, in save_session
10:52:16 web.1     |     return self.session_interface.save_session(self, session, response)
10:52:16 web.1     |   File "/Users/julius/twitter-sentiment/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/sessions.py", line 205, in save_session
10:52:16 web.1     |     secure=secure, domain=domain)
10:52:16 web.1     |   File "/Users/julius/twitter-sentiment/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/contrib/securecookie.py", line 329, in save_cookie
10:52:16 web.1     |     data = self.serialize(session_expires or expires)
10:52:16 web.1     |   File "/Users/julius/twitter-sentiment/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/contrib/securecookie.py", line 235, in serialize
10:52:16 web.1     |     self.quote(value)
10:52:16 web.1     |   File "/Users/julius/twitter-sentiment/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/contrib/securecookie.py", line 192, in quote
10:52:16 web.1     |     value = cls.serialization_method.dumps(value)
10:52:16 web.1     |   File "/Users/julius/twitter-sentiment/venv/bin/../lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 70, in _reduce_ex
10:52:16 web.1     |     raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
10:52:16 web.1     | TypeError: can't pickle function objects
```

I really hope something can help. I might be doing this in a completely wrong way (with passing the job via a session), but I have no idea how else to access the result of the job...

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I've not used `rq` before but I see that a job has a `.key` property. It might be easier to store that hash in your session. Then you can use the `Job` class's `.fetch` method which will itself call a `.refresh()` and return the job to you. Reading the `.result()` at that point would give you the job's current status.

Maybe like this (untested):

```py
from rq.job import Job

@app.route('/make/')
def make():
    job = q.enqueue(do_something, 'argument')
    session['job'] = job.key
    return 'Done'

@app.route('/get/')
def get():
    try:
        job = Job()
        job.fetch(session['job'])
        out = str(job.result)
    except:
        out = 'No result yet'
    return out
```

Comment: Hi @aezell did you manage to make rq work with SQLAlchemy and flask. I can't manage to get pass this problem: RuntimeError: application not registered on db instance and no application bound to current context

Comment: Hi @NguyenChienCong I actually am not using rq right now and just provided the above as some sample code to answer this question. It's hard to say what your problem might be without seeing some sample code. Perhaps it's worth posting a full SO question?

Comment: thanks @aezell , I managed to fix the the problem. You need in fact to import the whole app into the worker in order to have it own application context. I'm so used to Ruby and Rails with the autoload that I forgot about that. cheers

Comment: @NguyenChienCong this needs to be it's own Q&A it is exactly what I was having troubles with

Answer (score 2):

Problem with serializing arguments (you actually trying to serialize function object which is impossible with `pickle`).

Try

```
@app.route('/make/')
def make():
    job = q.enqueue(func=do_something, args=('argument',))
    session['job'] = job
    return 'Done'
```