# How to get Job by id in RQ python?

Tags: python, redis

So, basically I want to build a long-polling application which is using RQ on heroku. I have looked at this question [Flask: passing around background worker job (rq, redis)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162021/flask-passing-around-background-worker-job-rq-redis) but it doesn't help.

This is basically what I'm doing.

```
@app.route('/do_something', methods=['POST'])
def get_keywords():
    data_json = json.loads(request.data)
    text = urllib.unquote(data_json["sentence"])

    job = q.enqueue(keyword_extraction.extract, text)
    return job.key

@app.route('/do_something/<job_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_keywords_results(job_id):
    job = Job().fetch(job_id)

    if(not job.is_finished):
        return "Not yet", 202
    else:
        return str(job.result)
```

Nothing is fancy, so when the POST request comes, it will queue the job and return job_id back to user immidiately, and then user will use the key to keep polling the result. However, I can't seem to get this to work as this line `Job().fetch(job_id)` returns

`NoRedisConnectionException: Could not resolve a Redis connection.`

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Did you install a redis adon and properly set it up?

Comment: I tested it on my localhost. It works fine when the job is enqueued. But when I try to get it Job().fetch(job_id) it gives my that error.

Answer (score 22):

I found this out already, in case anybody is interested. It has to be this one instead.

```
Job.fetch(job_id, connection=conn)
```

Comment: Job is not available in the API now :(  Do you know any alternative?

Comment: Ah, found `q.fetch_job(job_id)`.

Comment: @ArunaHerath I found [another way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54624049/2052575) specifically for `v0.13.0`

Answer (score 4):

In RQ version `0.13.0` I found when running:

```
j = q.enqueue(job_func)
```

`j.key` will be the the key preceded by `rq:job:`.

Therefor elsewhere in the framework when fetching the job I need to use:

```
j = q.fetch_job(key[7:])
```

Where `j.result` will be `None` or the return value of `job_func`.

Not sure if there's a better way to handle this...

Answer (score 1):

This was due to a regression which is now fixed, see https://github.com/nvie/rq/issues/479 for the details.

You need to install from github master branch in order to resolve this, until this is released to PyPI.