# Flask Session UnpickleError

Tags: python, heroku, flask, redis, python-rq

I have a long running function which I want to run on heroku as a background function. I'm using redis and rq to manage this.

My dashboard view function which loads the data into the session object starts with:

```
@login_required
@main.route('/dash', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def dash():
    if request.method =='POST':
        print(request.form.get('posting'))
        session['posting']=request.form.get('posting')
        session['folder']=request.form.get('folder')
```

Then after selection the info gets passed to:

```
@login_required
@main.route('/confirm', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def confirm():
    print(session['posting'])
    return foreground_vs_background(confirm_function,[session])
```

Then:

```
def foreground_vs_background(func, args):

        j=  get_queue().enqueue(func,args = args,result_ttl=5000)
        return (j.get_id())
```

finally my function that I pass in starts with:

```
def confirm_function():
    p =  session['posting']
    folder  =  session['folder']
```

The heroku logs show:

```
2018-03-09T14:43:14.357633+00:00 app[worker.1]:     return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
2018-03-09T14:43:14.357642+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "manage.py", line 111, in run_worker
2018-03-09T14:43:14.357861+00:00 app[worker.1]:     worker.work()
2018-03-09T14:43:14.357870+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 460, in work
2018-03-09T14:43:14.360547+00:00 app[worker.1]:     self.execute_job(job, queue)
2018-03-09T14:43:14.360590+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 575, in execute_job
2018-03-09T14:43:14.360593+00:00 app[worker.1]:     self.fork_work_horse(job, queue)
2018-03-09T14:43:14.360594+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 521, in fork_work_horse
2018-03-09T14:43:14.360596+00:00 app[worker.1]:     self.main_work_horse(job, queue)
2018-03-09T14:43:14.360598+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 590, in main_work_horse
2018-03-09T14:43:14.360599+00:00 app[worker.1]:     success = self.perform_job(job, queue)
2018-03-09T14:43:14.360601+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 692, in perform_job
2018-03-09T14:43:14.360603+00:00 app[worker.1]:     self.prepare_job_execution(job)
2018-03-09T14:43:14.360604+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 624, in prepare_job_execution
2018-03-09T14:43:14.360610+00:00 app[worker.1]:     self.procline(msg.format(job.func_name, job.origin, time.time()))
2018-03-09T14:43:14.360612+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 241, in func_name
2018-03-09T14:43:14.360842+00:00 app[worker.1]:     self._unpickle_data()
2018-03-09T14:43:14.360848+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 209, in _unpickle_data
2018-03-09T14:43:14.361116+00:00 app[worker.1]:     self._func_name, self._instance, self._args, self._kwargs = unpickle(self.data)
2018-03-09T14:43:14.361121+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 53, in unpickle
2018-03-09T14:43:14.361329+00:00 app[worker.1]:     raise UnpickleError('Could not unpickle', pickled_string, e)
2018-03-09T14:43:14.361396+00:00 app[worker.1]: rq.exceptions.UnpickleError: ('Could not unpickle', RecursionError('maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object',)
)
2018-03-09T14:43:14.522562+00:00 app[worker.1]: 14:43:14 Moving job to 'failed' queue
```

I've been reading through [Flask: passing around background worker job (rq, redis)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162021/flask-passing-around-background-worker-job-rq-redis), which sounds like a similar problem, but I'm not clear on how to solve this to allow me to access the data I have stored inside the session object

Answer (score 1):

After struggling with this for a while , I've come to the conclusion that the it may not be possible to pass objects into RQ . I ended up turning the parameters into a json string and passing them in that way.

```
args= json.dumps({"posting": session['posting'], "folder": session['folder']})
```

then you can run:

```
 foreground_vs_background(myfunction, args):
```

Comment: Dammit. On 2019, still no way?